# cv.2imread() логирование в консоль

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, логирование, img

При считывание изображений в массив на python происходит логирование ( отображение) загрузки, вида:

```
100%|██████████| 390/390 [00:04<00:00, 78.33it/s]

100%|██████████| 234/234 [00:08<00:00, 27.84it/s]
```

При работе в notebook оно динамично и занимает две строчки, как показано выше.

Есть файл, который использует загрузку изображений в таком формате, при этом существует лог этого файла, куда записывается нужная информация.
Состояние же загрузки тоже записывается в лог, как понимаете весьма не динамично, а вроде такого:

```
 0%|          | 0/234 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  3%|▎         | 7/234 [00:00<00:03, 66.77it/s]
  6%|▋         | 15/234 [00:00<00:03, 69.14it/s]
 10%|▉         | 23/234 [00:00<00:02, 71.88it/s]
 14%|█▍        | 33/234 [00:00<00:02, 77.62it/s]
 18%|█▊        | 43/234 [00:00<00:02, 83.01it/s]
 22%|██▏       | 52/234 [00:00<00:02, 80.42it/s]
 26%|██▌       | 60/234 [00:00<00:02, 66.61it/s]
 29%|██▉       | 69/234 [00:00<00:02, 69.40it/s]
 34%|███▍      | 79/234 [00:01<00:02, 75.50it/s]
 38%|███▊      | 88/234 [00:01<00:01, 78.18it/s]
 41%|████      | 96/234 [00:01<00:01, 78.39it/s]
 46%|████▌     | 107/234 [00:01<00:01, 81.61it/s]
 50%|████▉     | 116/234 [00:01<00:01, 79.97it/s]
 53%|█████▎    | 125/234 [00:01<00:01, 75.12it/s]
 57%|█████▋    | 133/234 [00:01<00:01, 74.51it/s]
 60%|██████    | 141/234 [00:01<00:01, 65.41it/s]
 65%|██████▍   | 151/234 [00:01<00:01, 72.48it/s]
 69%|██████▉   | 161/234 [00:02<00:00, 76.43it/s]
 72%|███████▏  | 169/234 [00:02<00:00, 70.27it/s]
 76%|███████▌  | 177/234 [00:02<00:00, 65.74it/s]
 80%|███████▉  | 187/234 [00:02<00:00, 72.96it/s]
 84%|████████▍ | 196/234 [00:02<00:00, 77.03it/s]
 88%|████████▊ | 207/234 [00:02<00:00, 79.99it/s]
 92%|█████████▏| 216/234 [00:02<00:00, 75.52it/s]
 96%|█████████▌| 224/234 [00:02<00:00, 73.08it/s]
100%|██████████| 234/234 [00:03<00:00, 76.15it/s]
```

Как избавиться от этого в логе?

Вызов функции: (по умолчанию этот кусок кода содержится в файле, который вызывается так: `python -u fl_trainer.py $i > ${log_dir}/trainer$i.log 2>&1 &`)

```
test_reader = paddle.batch(
        paddle.reader.shuffle(
            xray_dataset.custom_reader_test(data_path_test),
            buf_size=500),
          batch_size=20)
```

Функция со считыванием изображений

```
def custom_reader_test(data_dir):

    def test():
        for label in labels: 
            path = os.path.join(data_dir, label)
            class_num = np.array([labels.index(label)])
             #print(class_num)
            for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
                img_arr = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            # print(img_arr.shape)
                res = cv2.resize(img_arr, dsize=(img_size, img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC).astype(float)
                res = res / 255
                yield res, class_num

    return test
```

Comment: А покажите минимальный код, с этой проблемой. Пока не очень понятно, особенно почему оно в файл пишет, по умолчанию, логгеры пишут только в stdout или в stderr (и, по умолчанию, эти же логеры не активны)

Comment: @gil9red, добавил внизу.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, в той команде ` > ` перенаправляет поток вывода приложения в файл, это объясняет почему лог с прогрессом попал. Чтобы в консоли сделать прогресс в одну строку, нужно сначала вывести первую строку, после на ее месте другую. Ваш вариант, я думаю, сделать логирование вручную из кода (можете сразу в файл и писать). Остается вопрос почему логирование видно, вы точно минимальный код показали или еще остался кусок, например, c logging.baseconfig?